# How to make a Repeating Alarm for API 23 , 19 And less

Tags: java, android

I really want to know How to make a Repeating Alarm for API 23, 19 And less
I searched so much but I can't understand how to make it.

What I get is to use:

`alarmManger.setExactAndAllowWholeIdle` --> for api 23

And

`SetExact` --> for API 19 and more

But I don't know how to repeat them!

And 
`Setrepeating` --> for API 14 and more

The problem with API 23 AND 19

So please if anyone can help me by an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using a Service

this is part of my code

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAzkarBroad.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RC, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, hour, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

the start an intent to the broadcast

Answer (score 1):

you can create a runnable class that will execute the pending intent of alarm manager class:

```
public class Alarm_task implements Runnable {

    // The date selected for the alarm
    private final Calendar cal;
    // The android system alarm manager
    private final AlarmManager am;
    // Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
    private final Context context;
    long alarm_time2;
    int _id;

    public Alarm_task(Context context, Calendar cal) {
        this.context = context;
        this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.cal = cal;
        this._id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        alarm_time2 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), alarm_time2 + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us
        // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
        Intent i = new Intent("com.package_name.alarm");
        i.setAction("com.package_name.alarm");
        /** Creating a Pending Intent */
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), _id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        /** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
        long alarm_time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), alarm_time+" " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
        // am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);
        //this line will repeat the alarm in 24 hour interval
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, operation);
    }
}
```

Now call this alarm task:

```
    //here set your desired time for the alarm
    String dateString = "11/21/2016 11:49:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    calNow.setTime(date);
    long current_time = calNow.getTimeInMillis();
    new Alarm_task(getActivity(), calNow).run();
```

you can define a class for handling the particular pending intent in the menifest file

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.package_name.Prereminder"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.package_name.alarm" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now in the prereminder class you can show dialog or show notification during that time:
  Prereminder.java

```
public class Prereminder extends FragmentActivity {

String msg = "Alarm Title";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    sendNotification();
    /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
    Reminder_alert alert = new Reminder_alert();
    /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
    alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Reminder_alert");
}


private void sendNotification() {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //handle notification onClick
    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Home_page.class);
    myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_small)
                    .setContentTitle("Alarm alert")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
   }
}
```

Show the dialog message in Reminder_alert.java

```
public class Reminder_alert extends DialogFragment {

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);


    /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
    builder.setTitle("Alarm");

    /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
    builder.setMessage("Alarm alert");

    /** Defining an OK button event listener */
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    /** Creating the alert dialog window */
    return builder.create();
}

/**
 * The application should be exit, if the user presses the back button
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().finish();
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using a broadcast Receiver and it contain the notification details that will triggered at alarm time  ...... so I can replace the package name with the broadcast or what .... I can't understand , be patient plz